# How to build Qmake for Visual studio project? specifically for QGLViewer for octomap library

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, qmake, octomap

I need to build an [octomap](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/blob/devel/octovis/README.md#microsoft-visual-studio-2010) on visual studio 2017. According to website they have asked to do the following

```
open a windows shell (e.g., from the START-Menu -> QT)
    cd octovis/src/extern/QGLViewer
    qmake -t vclib QGLViewer.pro -spec win32-msvc2010    (ignore any warnings)
```

So I did the same but in windows command prompt terminal and when I feed the above commands it throws the following error:

```
#qmake -t vclib QGLViewer.pro -spec win32-msvc2010 

Could not find qmake spec 'win32-msvc2010'.
Error processing project file: QGLViewer.pro 

 #qmake -t vclib QGLViewer.pro -spec win32-msvc2017 

Could not find qmake spec 'win32-msvc2017'.
Error processing project file: QGLViewer.pro
```

**What should I do in order to configure and generate a QGLViewer.vcxproj?**

Additional details:

1. Project location : "C:\software\octomap-1.9.0\octomap-1.9.0\octovis\src\extern\QGLViewer"
2. qmake location : C:\vcpkg\packages\qt5-base_x64-windows\tools\qt5
3. Visual studio : 2017 ( Version 15.9.8)

Any help in regards to this would be much appreciated as I have a very limited understanding on qmake.

Comment: I think it should be `win32-msvc` instead of `'win32-msvc2010'`

Comment: Basically, qmake tells you that `win32-msvc2010` file does not exist. Specs are qmake configuration files for specific platforms. To get their location dir, execute `qmake -query QMAKE_MKSPECS`. Or just search for dir `mkspecs` in qt folders. Look there and try to pick the most appropriate spec for win and msvc, if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can build QGLViewer with Qt Creator instead, and then it just works - I was bashing my head against the same issue as you for a while, but then just tried that and it solved my problems. For what it's worth, I used Qt Creator 4.12.4 and did a build all.

I had a few other issues building Octovis on Windows that you might run up against as well. See here for the changes I had to make: https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/compare/devel...sgolodetz:winchanges